# IntelliJ (Kotlin) Visual Unresolved Reference Bug

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea

I have imported a dependency in my Maven Local repository into a project I am working on for a Minecraft Server. I recently updated the dependency from 2.1.1 to 2.1.2 (and changed the repository to MavenLocal from a public one for testing), cause I added a new feature and wanted to test it out. As of updating it, I started getting IntelliJ errors saying that all the methods from this dependency were unresolved, however, the project builds fine [(see image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55SIZ.png).

When I examine the contents of my Jar, the dependency is in there, it shows exactly as I would expect in the gradle dependencies tab of IntelliJ as well as the External Libraries tab on the left project panel.

So far I have tried

- File > Invalidate Caches & Restart multiple times
- Reinstall the dependency to maven local (as well as delete it entirely from there so it was fresh) multiple times
- Reload gradle project multiple times
- Restart my PC

If anyone has any ideas as to why this might be happening or even steps I could take to debug the issue, that would be awesome. Thanks.

Comment: If you revert back to the old version do you have the same issue?

Comment: Yes, same visual bug. It builds fine but shows the visual bug that it is an unresolved reference.

Answer (score 0):

The bug seems to only be when it's in my local repository (for any version). When I reposted it on a public repo and then included it like that, it was fine. I submitted an issue with JetBrains and I'll see what they say.